# Meaning of "As It Happened"

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*as it happened*."  When I googled the phrase "*euro 2016*" around July 3, 2016 in the pacific time zone, this headline from the British newspaper [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/live/2016/jul/03/france-iceland-euro-2016-live) came up:

> France 5-2 Iceland: Euro 2016 quarter-final – ***as it happened***

What is "*as it happened*" supposed to mean in this context?

Comment: A media outlet can bring news of an event "as it happens" -- that is, as the event is unfolding. **as it happens** is a stock media phrase that means, more or less, "there won't be another news outlet where you can get news about this event sooner than you will get it here from us." I have not seen **as it happened** used of a report after-the-fact.  It doesn't quite make sense to me, given what the present-tense version usually means.  It could imply a retrospective as-it-unfolded commentary on the event.

Answer (score 3):

I found this thing
[image]

on that page. Anyway, I don't think it has a particular idiomatic meaning. I think *as* has the meaning *in the way that*. So the details are presented (in the following page) *in the way that* they happened. They provide to you second-by-second/minute-by-minute updates/playback so that you know the details and when/at what time they happened.